# What energy changes take place when you operate a jet-ski?

Tags: energy

What energy changes take place when you operate a [jet-ski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_ski)?

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how-does_4568986_how-jet-skis-work.html

This might help answer some questions. Electrical energy to heat and kinetic energy essentially

Comment: What have you thought about so far?

Comment: Questions are expected to show research effort. If this is homework, please use the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

- [Potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy): The jet-ski changes its position relative to the ground.
- [Kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy): The jet-ski itself moves.
- [Electrochemical energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_energy_conversion): Energy bound in the fuel of the jet-ski is used to accelerate the jet-ski.